# EF code first - one-to-one-or-zero

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have 2 entities:

```
public partial class GPSdevice
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public GPSdevice()
    {
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }


    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }

}


public partial class Truck
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Truck()
    {
    }

    public int TruckID { get; set; }

    public string TruckNo { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GPSdevice")]
    public int? GPSdeviceID { get; set; }

    public virtual GPSdevice GPSdevice { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a relationship one-to-one-or-zero (each GPSdevice can be linked to any truck (but to one and only one) or not linked at all)

I write the following code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<GPSdevice>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Truck)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

but it creates the following migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Truck", "GPSdevice_ID", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Truck", "GPSdeviceID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Truck", "GPSdevice_ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Truck", "GPSdeviceID", "dbo.GPSdevices", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Truck", "GPSdevice_ID", "dbo.GPSdevices", "ID");
    }
```

why it creates one more field and how to use the current field GPSdeviceID instead?

**ADDED:**

If I remove

```
public int? GPSdeviceID { get; set; }
```

and add MapKey:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<GPSdevice>()
        .HasOptional(e => e.Truck)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(e=>e.GPSdevice).Map(p=>p.MapKey("GPSdeviceID"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

in result I get the following migration code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.Truck", "GPSdeviceID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Truck", "GPSdeviceID", "dbo.GPSdevices", "ID");
    }
```

then I get the following error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.GPSdevices' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_dbo.Truck_dbo.GPSdevices_GPSdeviceID'. Could not create
>   constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: You can't. `HasForeignKey` fluent API is missing for this type of relationship for a purpose - to indicate that explicit FK is not supported (I can't tell why). Remove `public int? GPSdeviceID { get; set; }` property and eventually use `MapKey` to specify the FK database column name.

Comment: @IvanStoev then I get: "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.GPSdevices' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.Truck_dbo.GPSdevices_GPSdeviceID'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."

Comment: Just noticed you didn't map the inverse navigation property correctly. So in addition to the first comment, change `.WithOptionalPrincipal()` to `.WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.GPSdevice)`.

Comment: @IvanStoev see my added code

Comment: That's another story. You have existing data in the database tables which violates the constraint. Check Truck table for a record with GPSdeviceID value w/o matching ID value from the GPSDevices table.

Comment: SQL Server says that you don't have ID column on GPSDevices table. You could have lost it during tests. Check also Truck table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public partial class GPSdevice
{       
    public GPSdevice()
    {
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }


    public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }

}

public partial class Truck
{       
    public Truck()
    {
    }

    public int TruckID { get; set; }

    public string TruckNo { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public virtual GPSdevice GPSdevice { get; set; }
}   

modelBuilder.Entity<GPSdevice>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.Truck)
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.GPSdevice);

modelBuilder.Entity<Truck>()
    .HasKey(e => e.TruckID);
```